# Packaging a CMake project (libRocket) into a .deb, but build script is in a sub folder

Tags: packaging, deb, dh-make

I am trying to build a .deb package for libRocket (http://librocket.com/), but the build script is not in the source root but rather in a subfolder (/Build). See the Github source:

https://github.com/lloydw/libRocket

I can build it fine, using:

```
cd Build
cmake -DBUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS=on
```

I have tried debianising the project using dh_make but can't seem to figure out how to get it to look in the Build folder for a CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: The options go after the `$@`: dh $@ --buildsystem=cmake --sourcedirectory=Build

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `debian/rules` file is the script that runs the build process. You can tell it that the build script is in a sub folder by passing `--sourcedirectory=Build` So your's might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@ --buildsystem=cmake --sourcedirectory=Build
```

See the [manpage for the `dh` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dh.1.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, you got me going in the right direction, the manpage link is invalid, but "man dh" got me what I needed. Also, there is no need for the / before Build.

Comment: Great. Fixed above.

Comment: @robvdl , Could accept this answer if it works for you. See https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @andrewsomething can you answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/851419/dh-install-o-buildsystem-cmake-dh-install-missing-files-usr-lib-lib-so ?

Comment: Add `usr/lib/*/cmak/*` into dev.install file if your modules provides cmake files