# dh_install -O--buildsystem=cmake dh_install: missing files: usr/lib/*/lib*.so

Tags: packaging, cmake

I am trying to publish my **cmake** project to ppa at launchpad. The project is a library named "base".

`bzr builddeb -- -us -uc -sd` fails with following error while trying to  fake install **`dev`** version of the package.

```
...
...
Install the project...
/usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
-- Install configuration: "None"
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/lib/libbase.so.1.0
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/lib/libbase.so.1
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/lib/libbase.so
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/include/ferryfair/base/myxml.h
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/include/ferryfair/base/Socket.h
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/include/ferryfair/base/ClientSocket.h
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/include/ferryfair/base/mycurl.h
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/include/ferryfair/base/mystdlib.h
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/include/ferryfair/base/ServerSocket.h
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/include/ferryfair/base/JPEGImage.h
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/include/ferryfair/base/SocketException.h
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/include/ferryfair/base/FerryTimeStamp.h
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/include/ferryfair/base/myconverters.h
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/include/ferryfair/base/baseConfig.h
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libbase.pc
-- Installing: /home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/debian/tmp/usr/share/pkgconfig/libbase.pc
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/gowtham/Packages/build-area/base-1.1/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu'
  dh_install -O--buildsystem=cmake
dh_install: base-dev missing files: usr/lib/*/lib*.so
dh_install: base-dev missing files: usr/lib/*/pkgconfig/*
dh_install: base1 missing files: usr/lib/*/lib*.so.*
dh_install: missing files, aborting
debian/rules:11: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 20
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc -sd failed
bzr: ERROR: The build failed.
```

how to differ `builddeb` for **`dev`** version of the package at installing **`header files`**

**debian/rules**

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

override_dh_auto_test:
override_dh_usrlocal:

%:
    dh $@ --buildsystem=cmake
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths in `base-dev.install` and `base1.install` are wrong.

> ```
> dh_install: base-dev missing files: usr/lib/*/lib*.so
> dh_install: base-dev missing files: usr/lib/*/pkgconfig/*
> dh_install: base1 missing files: usr/lib/*/lib*.so.*
> ```

They will be correct as below and package can be built:

```
usr/lib/lib*.so
usr/lib/pkgconfig/*

usr/lib/lib*.so.*
```

But you will have `lintian` messages that `/usr/lib/` is not safe for multi-arch system installations.

- Either you fix it at source level (as upstream developer), so `cmake` install those files to `/usr/lib/<HOST-ARCH-FOLDER>/`. Which is the correct way.
- Or you fix it at packaging level (as packager), by overriding installation paths in `base-dev.install` and `base1.install`

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/dh-exec

  usr/lib/lib*.so /usr/lib/${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH}
  usr/lib/pkgconfig/* /usr/lib/${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH}/pkgconfig

  usr/lib/lib*.so.* /usr/lib/${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH}
  ```

Comment: Though I intend to run my library on multiple architectures, I didn't write any thing specific for each architecture. So is it proper to put my library under architecture folder?

Comment: @neckTwi, in multi-arch systems, user can install base1:amd64 or/and base1:i386, (1) your packages overwrite same files, you should put in `debian/control` that they break each other.  (2) Can a program linked to an architecture run versus the other one, if your library is explicitly verified for portability between arch's then you are safe.

Comment: do multi-arch systems exist!! I always thought a system is of single architecture at a time.

Comment: @neckTwi, yeah its support starts with Ubuntu 12.04 . If you have a 64bit base installation you can enable 32bit packages installation. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit/ . You may notice that `wine`, `skype` and few 3rd party tools are released as i386 (32bit) for Ubuntu >=12.04, whatever the system is amd64 or i386 same package could be installed with all its i386 dependencies.

Comment: yes, thank you. Please look into my other question http://askubuntu.com/questions/852164/dh-auto-configure-with-buildsystem-cmake-failing

Comment: pbuild is not including `/usr/lib/${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH}` by default I have to do `link_directories(/usr/lib/${DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH})` in `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: @neckTwi , Which Ubuntu release and cmake version you are using? I was expecting `cmake` will use same paths used by `ld`. In Ubuntu 16.04 64bit, the are declared in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf` & `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu.conf` .  (possible bug report)

Comment: I think I am wrong; I am building another package(`logger`) dependent on my previous package(`base`). I have done `sudo cp ~/pbuilder/xenial-base.tgz /var/cache/pbuilder/base.tgz`
`pbuilder login --save-after-login` `apt-add-repository ppa:satyagowtham-k-gmail/ferryfair.ppa`

Comment: please look into http://askubuntu.com/questions/853890/dpkg-shlibdeps-error-couldnt-find-library-needed-by-so-while-packaging-a-pac thank you