# dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library needed by .so while packaging a package dependent on my another package

Tags: dependencies, ppa, packaging

I have packaged a library named `base` and uploaded to my `ppa:satyagowtham-k-gmail/ferryfair.ppa`. launchpad has successfully built the `base` package and I successfully installed it by `sudo apt install base-dev`. Now I am packaging another library called `logger` which depends on `base`.

I have added my `ppa` to `pbuilder chroot` by

```
$ sudo cp ~/pbuilder/xenial-base.tgz /var/cache/pbuilder/base.tgz
$ pbuilder login --save-after-login
# apt-add-repository ppa:satyagowtham-k-gmail/ferryfair.ppa
# apt-get update
# exit
```

**pbuilder-dist xenial build logger_1.0-0ubuntu1.dsc** is giving below error

```
...
...
install -d debian/logger-dev/DEBIAN
    dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/logger1.substvars -l/build/logger-1.0/lib/x86_64 --ignore-missing-info debian/logger1/usr/lib/x86_64/liblogger.so.1.0
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: couldn't find library libbase.so.1 needed by debian/logger1/usr/lib/x86_64/liblogger.so.1.0 (ELF format: 'elf64-x86-64'; RPATH: '')
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: cannot continue due to the error above
Note: libraries are not searched in other binary packages that do not have any shlibs or symbols file.
To help dpkg-shlibdeps find private libraries, you might need to use -l.
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/logger1.substvars -l/build/logger-1.0/lib/x86_64 --ignore-missing-info debian/logger1/usr/lib/x86_64/liblogger.so.1.0 returned exit code 2
debian/rules:10: recipe for target 'override_dh_shlibdeps' failed
make[1]: *** [override_dh_shlibdeps] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/build/logger-1.0'
debian/rules:13: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
...
...
```

**debian/rules**

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
export DH_VERBOSE=1

override_dh_auto_test:
override_dh_usrlocal:
override_dh_shlibdeps:
    dh_shlibdeps --dpkg-shlibdeps-params=--ignore-missing-info -l$(shell pwd)/lib/$(shell uname -m)

%:
    dh $@ --buildsystem=cmake
```

**debian/control**

```
Source: logger
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Satya Gowtham Kudupudi <satyagowtham.k@gmail.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), cmake, base-dev
Standards-Version: 3.9.7
Section: non-free/libs
Homepage: https://github.com/necktwi/logger
Vcs-Git: https://github.com/necktwi/logger.git
Vcs-Browser: https://github.com/necktwi/logger

Package: logger-dev
Section: non-free/libdevel
Architecture: any
Depends: logger1 (= ${binary:Version}), ${misc:Depends}, base1
Description: logger from ferryfair.com
 It logs a beautiful and useful format.

Package: logger1
Section: non-free/libs
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends},  base1
Description: logger from ferryfair.com
 It logs a beautiful and useful format.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The problem resides in the `base` package. It does install the shared object in a wrong path

  ```
    /usr/lib/x86_64/
  ```

  when it should be in

  ```
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
  ```
- Following from your previous question, you have made some changes to `CMakeLists.txt` to install the library not in `/usr/lib/` using:

  ```
    include(TargetArch.cmake)
    target_architecture(arch)
    ...
    install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION lib/${arch})
    ...
    install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.pc"
        DESTINATION lib/${arch}/pkgconfig
        RENAME "lib${PROJECT_NAME}.pc")
  ```

  The new variable `${arch}` is replaced by `x86_64`.
- I could find [a Debian manual explains the move to MultiArch for `cmake` projects](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Implementation#CMake).

  A new [GNUInstallDirs module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) was added to cmake v3.3.

  1. Include the new module for MultiArch paths support

     ```
      include(GNUInstallDirs)
     ```
  2. Then use `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` (`/usr/lib/<triplet>`) variable instead.
- Just small note about `base` package naming to follow Debian policy the binary file don't contain executable files. Hence, better to name them with `lib` prefix, `libbase1` & `libbase-dev`.

Comment: I couldn't `pbuilder-dist`: `base1 base-dev Untrusted packages could compromise your system's security`. anyway I have uploaded the `dsc` and the package is successfully hosted in the `ppa`.

Comment: as you suggested I have added `lib` prefix. now there is a lintian warning `W: libbase1: empty-binary-package`.  Yep I have seen the contents of `.deb`: It got only 2 files `changelog.Debian.gz`  and `copyright`

Comment: @neckTwi, Have you renamed the `debian/*.install` files?

Comment: there are no .install files

Comment: this time I am using `gbp buildpackage --git-upstream-tag='v1.0' --git-debian-branch=ubuntu/xenial --git-upstream-branch=master` to generate deb files

Comment: I don't see any `ubuntu/xenial`  branch in your git repositories at https://github.com/necktwi/base & https://github.com/necktwi/logger

Comment: @neckTwi, also no tag  with this label `v1.0` . try simple use as you have debian folder in same tree/branch with the source `gbp buildpackage`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49256/discussion-between-necktwi-and-user-dz).